# Are "not to be taken" and "not to take" interchangable?

Tags: grammar

I know the following sentence is grammatically correct. However, I was wondering if I could replace 'not to be taken' with 'not to take'?

> The use of humor with aggressive actions is a way to communicate that the action was **not to be taken** seriously.

Comment: If _the action_ is the subject, then the verb phrase has to be _is not be taken_; if the subject is whoever takes the action, then the verb phrase should be "not to take". The agent should be the subject of an active verb phrase, while the patient should be the subject of a passive verb phrase.

Comment: That depends.  Do you want the action not to take seriously?  I assume not, as it seems quite nonsensical.

Comment: @JohnLawler Should that be posted as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: it should read _... then the verb phrase has to be is not **to** be taken._

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter stated, the issue with your suggested phrasing is that it makes *action* the agent of its clause, so by conjugating the verb as *to take* you are attributing it to *action*. Your action isn't taking, it is *being* taken, by the observers of said action. Accordingly, the original sentence you provided is the only correct phrasing of this meaning.

You could use your suggested phrasing by altering the sentence slightly, however:

> The use of humor with aggressive actions is a way to indicate *not to take* **them** seriously.